# Is there a way to call the 'predict' method of a Spark ML MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel?

Tags: neural-network, apache-spark-mllib

For older ML models such as DecisionTreeModel it is possible to load a stored model and apply it directly to a single data point (feature vector) like this:

```
val features: Vector = <some vector of floats representing feature values> 
val modelDT = DecisionTreeModel.load(sparkContext, <"some-path">)
val prediction = modelDT.predict(features)
```

For MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel the predict method is protected and can't be called.  The features need to be wrapped in a Dataset, and the result is returned as a DataFrame with one row.  This is cumbersome and adds a lot of overhead for a real-time system that classifies one point at a time.

Comment: same problem. Also, I don't get a confidence level for the prediction. Is there a way to get the confidence level?

Answer (score 0):

So if you have the model loaded like this:

```
model = MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel.load("Path.model")
```

or one that you have trained before.

Then put your input data without a known label in this form

```
test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(features=Vectors.sparse(4, {1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: -1.0, 4: 1.0}))]).toDF()

result = model.transform(test).head().prediction

print(result)
```

You can also do Vectors.dense or the other sparse declarations

There are a few things that you need to import such as:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import MultilayerPerceptronClassifier, MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel
from pyspark.sql import Row
```